# How to push to github from cloud9?

Tags: git, github, cloud9-ide

I am trying to push some changes from cloud9 to a github repository but I am hitting a roadblock.

I can clone OK with ssh, and everything seems to be OK, I make my changes, save the changes in cloud9 (when I go back the changes are still there), then I do `git commit` and get:

```
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

but I just need to commit changes to an existing file not to add. So obviously when I try to `git push origin master` there's nothing to push.

I tried with multiple github repos and I get the same result.

What am I missing?

Any help appreciated!

P.S. Oh, btw I suck at git

Comment: Did you do a git add before the commit?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The message shows that you are not adding changed/tracked files to commit.

Try with `-am` switch to ADD and Commit in one operation:

```
git commit -am "your message goes here"
git push
```

Comment: Be careful with this, you can commit things you didn't know had changed.

Answer (score 7):

Git separates committing from adding *changes*. You first have to add all changes you want to appear in the commit:

```
#1: Add any new files as part of the commit
#   or use git add -p to interactively select hunks to stage
git add file1 file2 …

#2: Commit to local
git commit -m "Commit message goes here"

#3: Push your commit/changes to the host (github)
git push
```

You should now have all your changes on github.

Alternatively, you can do the commit, and add/modify in one line, this may include undesired files into your changeset.

```
#1 Add files commit to local
git commit -a -m "Commit message goes here"

#2 Push your commit/messages to the host (github)
git push
```

Comment: Thank you... did the command above, but didn't know about the push portion.. really green when it comes to git.

Comment: @Tracker1: thanks for editing my answer, but I think it would have been better if you provided it as your own answer – you have re-written quite a bunch. Also, you removed the explicit `origin master` from `git push`, which often does the expected thing with fewer surprises

Comment: I removed the origin master, as in cloud9 to github, that option stopped working for me, while "git push" worked as expected.. :)  Just the same, trying to be helpful with what was the most correct answer.